# ArrayList to ArrayList<Type>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, types, casting

What's the easiest way to convert an `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<Type>` without the "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning? More specifically, what's the easiest way to deal with the situation below?

```
public static void doStuff(ArrayList... a) {
    // stuff
}
```

I want to be able to call the method with any number of parameters, which means `a` will be an array and so I can't specify the type. So unless there's an alternate solution, I have an array of ArrayLists that I need to convert into `ArrayList<Type>`.

Comment: `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")`

Comment: There's no way to have a generic array (varargs is an array) without unchecked conversion. Whether or not it's safe depends on what `// stuff` does.

Comment: I recommend you post the real question. Always a bad idea to think you have to do something then ask about that. There probably is a better overall solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to convert a plain `ArrayList` to an `ArrayList<Type>` then it logically is an unsafe conversion, because the compiler can't guarantee the types will line up. If it is not an issue in this case, ignore or suppress the warning. It is just telling you to be careful: it doesn't necessarily mean there is a problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that its not required that anything be added or removed from the `List` you could do

```
public static void doStuff(List<?>... list) {
```

Given that `ArrayList` is a variable size collection it probably makes more sense to use

```
public static void doStuff(List<?> list) {
```